# Laravel Storage Delete/Clean Not Working on Production Server

Tags: php, laravel, cron, filesystems, storage

We have Cron to clear file in the folder / delete the directory in storage. None of below is working (No Error Occurred. Seem Like Passing Through Without Error). But magically in Local is working. When i run the cron in production server using  `SUDO php artisan cms:clear_bill` is working. How to run it without sudo ?

I already check the folder of user_bill permission is 755 and all the files inside it 644..

```
$file = new Filesystem();
$file->deleteDirectory(storage_path('app/public/user_bill'));
$file->cleanDirectory(storage_path('app/public/user_bill'));
Storage::deleteDirectory(storage_path('app/public/user_bill'));
```

Is there any step that I miss?

---

## Solved

Dammit permission.. the cron is running not under the user of the project..

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an error or does nothing happen?

Comment: not getting any errors..EDIT

Comment: What user is the cron run as? You can only delete the files if the user you run the script as has permission to do so.